# Missing icons in Nautilus

Tags: linux, gnome, nautilus

I've installed Fedora 18 (x64) minimum and I installed Enlightenment with Nautilus. But I see that there are icons missing in Nautilus, I have selected the gnome icon theme so I must be missing some package(s).

Does anyone know which ones?

#### screenshot

[image: ss of missing icons]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Potential solution #1

Try these 2 commands first:

```
gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/gnome
gtk-update-icon-cache /usr/share/icons/hicolor
```

#### Potential solution #2

If that doesn't resolve the issue try installing this RPM, `alacarte`.

```
yum install alacarte
```

#### Potential solution #3

```
yum install 'gnome-icon-theme*'
```

Comment: The first 2 commands and installing alacarte doesn't work. And when I try to install alacarte I get this error: http://pastebin.com/XkDxU0iF

Comment: What was the error? Also did you reboot after doing those commands?

Comment: Not sure of that error, try #3 first. Alacarte was a way to try and get an RPM installed that needed the GNOME icons. If 3 doesn't work we'll circle back to that one.

Comment: Solution #3 worked for me. I'd just reinstalled ubuntu (Pop!_OS 18.04 LTS), and all my icons were missing in Nautilus. Installing the gnome-icon-them, and then updating the gtk icon cach (#1) fixed the issue, and restored my icons.

Answer (score 0):

if you add new user and everything is ok, you can delete this file in your current user:

```
~/.config/dconf/user
```

this is gnome database and everythings about gnome return to first time you run it.